# Information Selection with Because

Tags: english, grammar, logic

I'm having difficulty with the extraction of information from sentences containing the word "because."

I was analyzing a text about the advantages and disadvantages of open-plan offices. When asked, "Why are open-plan offices good?", the answers extracted from the text, especially those before the word "because," seemed straightforward. For instance, "open-plan offices are cheaper for companies because they use less electricity" led to the primary advantage being "open-plan offices are cheaper for companies." The book's answer keys confirm this.

However, when discussing disadvantages, the extraction became inconsistent. From the sentence "Some people do not work well in open-plan offices because they are noisy," the primary disadvantage taken was "they are noisy" (from the "because" clause) rather than "Some people do not work well in open-plan offices." Yet, in another sentence "researchers think that people get ill more easily because they work near each other," the primary disadvantage extracted was "people get ill more easily" (from the independent clause).

Why is the information from the "because" clause prioritized in one instance and not in another? Is there a grammatical or semantic rule that I'm overlooking?

Here's the text for reference:

> ##### Open-plan offices: new research
>
> ###### The research
>
> People all around the world work in offices. Some people work in small offices for one or two people, but a lot of people now work in open-plan offices. In these offices, people work together in one big room. New research from Australia shows that there are advantages and disadvantages to these offices.
>
> ###### What’s good?
>
> The research shows three reasons to have open-plan offices. Firstly, in open-plan offices a lot of people can work in a small area. Secondly, it is easy for people to talk to work colleagues because they are in the same room. Finally, open-plan offices are cheaper for companies because they use less electricity.
>
> ###### What’s bad?
>
> The research also shows some disadvantages. Some people do not work well in open-plan offices because they are noisy. It is also difficult to talk privately in open-plan offices. Finally, researchers think that people get ill more easily because they work near each other.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don’t understand the rationale behind how you arrive at this ‘inconsistency’ (it doesn’t seem inconsistent to me). The disadvantages to the company are that people (1) do not work well in open-plan offices and (2) get ill more easily in them. The fact that they’re noisy is not a direct disadvantage here – it’s a factor that causes or leads to a disadvantage (inability to concentrate = less efficient work). Similarly, employees working in close proximity to each other is not a direct disadvantage to the company, but it leads to a disadvantage (increased disease flow = fewer people working).

Comment: Well, but the book's answer keys say "noisy" is one of the disadvantages, not "some people don't work well in open-plan offices", which I found more sensible when it comes to listing pros and cons. If you say people don't work well in open-plan offices is a disadvantage, then what about traditional offices? People do have the same line of argument for those offices, don't they? Being noisy is a distinct disadvantage here.

Comment: How is open-plan offices being noisy a disadvantage _to the company_? What’s financially disadvantageous about noise in and of itself? There is no direct link between noise and the company’s bottom line. The book’s answer is just wrong here, I’d say. I don’t understand what you mean by “the same line of argument” for traditional offices (by which I guess you mean those occupied by just one or two employees) – what line of argument? Noise?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What I meant was when you list out pros and cons of something, you tend to stick to the distinct characteristics  of the thing. Being noisy is something that "characterizes" open-plan offices. Saying something like "some people don't work well in open-plan offices" is just like saying "some people don't work well in traditional offices." It's not wrong, just weird. Being noisy is clearly a better option here. And the book probably means open-plan offices are noisier than traditional offices.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Also, the question was: "What are the disadvantages of open-plan offices?" Not sure why you keep insisting the "to company" part.

I imagine if this were an article on the Internet, saying "some people don't wok well in open-plan offices" would simply be a boring and obvious way to list out the disadvantages of open-plan offices. "They are noisy" would be much more effective and it would be chosen as a tagline/sub-header, not the one you suggested.

Comment: I extrapolated from the advantage, where it says open-plan offices are cheaper _for companies_ because they use less electricity. The statements you’ve picked out here don’t have the same structure and don’t describe the same things – they’re not parallel. Some have the offices as the topic, some have the employees, the company or other factors as the topic. Language is not logic, and you cannot expect natural language to have perfectly comparable structures throughout. _Because_ indicates a reason in all the examples given; that’s all.

Comment: Also, it’s not true that you list the characteristics of something when listing pros and cons. A _characteristic_ is not the same as a _(dis)advantage_. Closer proximity is a characteristic of open-plan offices, but it is not in and of itself a pro or a con, as evidenced by the fact that it shows up under both categories. When listing pros and cons of X, we list just that: pros and cons. Whether they’re characteristics of X or not.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, but saying "Some people don't work well in X" as a disadvantage is just strange, sorry. I never said we must include the characteristics, but we should stick to them for the analysis, not stating something obvious like you suggested. Just ask people "What are the disadvantages of open-plan offlices?" and give them the two answers we mentioned to see which makes more sense. What I'm asking is why we prefer or prioritize some info in because clauses when it comes to answering questions like this. You choosing a different answer from the book just showed that!

Comment: No, there is nothing strange about mentioning a tendency for people not to work well there as a disadvantage of a type of office space. That’s a very real and very relevant disadvantage. It’s obviously not meant to indicate that it applies to one in 10,000 people, because that would be true of _any_ kind of work environment. It is an unambiguous implication that it means _more_ people than what you’re comparing to (in this case traditional offices).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet erm... sorry, still weird to me. Why stating the obvious? We know that already. We know when something exists, it won't be able to make everyone happy. If you listed that reason out in an article about open-plan offices, I would say that's lazy writing. Sure, I agree with the message that it's not for everyone, but don't use that as an item/part in your analysis. And I don't think the authors who wrote that text thought the same as you do, evident in their answers. Let's just stop. Appreciate the ideas, though.

Comment: Only your textbook's authors can explain why they chose the answers they did. I don't think there's any linguistic rule that's operating here.